# Dynamically importing files into React component

Tags: reactjs

I'm using create-react-app and a couple external modules, like react-markdown. How do I 'require' a dynamically generated filename? I have thousands of markdown files and I need to load them on the fly. My component works fine if I supply a static path, but doesn't work when I try to concatenate the path. I can't import statically because there are too many files.

Example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown/with-html"

const MarkdownServer = ({myMarkdownFilename}) => {  
  const [markdown, setValue] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      // this works...
      // const p = require("../../assets/markdown/mymarkdown.md") 

      // this does not.
      const p = require("../../assets/markdown/" + myMarkdownFilename);
      const markdown = await fetch(p).then(res => res.text());
      setValue(markdown);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <p>
      <ReactMarkdown source={ markdown } escapeHtml={false} />
    </p>
  );
};

export default MarkdownServer;
```

Error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Cannot find module '../../assets/markdown/mymarkdown.md'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using React's `lazy` and `suspense` API's for dynamic [importing](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#import)?

I haven't gotten to use it myself yet but it seems like you could replace the `require()` with something like `const p = React.lazy(() => import("../../assets/markdown/" + myMarkdownFilename));` and then have the `return` statement render the `ReactMarkdown` component inside of a `Suspense` component.

If you're using webpack you might also want to look [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression):

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Lazy import should do job but you don't need Suspense for it.

Comment: Just tried this, along with the "loadable" module, and neither work.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to create a context module with the [Webpack context module API](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression). With a bit of regex, I was able to require the markdown docs.

After my standard imports:

```
const cache = {};

function importAll (r) {
  r.keys().forEach(key => cache[key] = r(key));
}

importAll(require.context("../../assets/markdown/", true, /\.md$/));
```

The cache object now contains the required files and their hashed names as name:value pairs. In my code I simply build the filename and use it to access the property:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      filepath = "../../assets/markdown/" + myMarkdownFilename
      const p = cache[filepath]
      const markdown = await fetch(p).then(res => res.text());
      setValue(markdown);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

This being said, there really ought to be a saner way to import static assets.